Coriolis force and objects falling down a hole drilled through the earth
If a hole was drilled into the earth from a place on the equator where linear velocity is maximum, and drilled down to earth's core, I believe an object dropped into it would be thrown against the east wall of the hole as earth's linear velocity due to rotation decreases with depth.
But I'm reading comments in other posts here that say an object thrown upward has less angular velocity the higher it was thrown, which is why it will always land slightly west of the point it was thrown from. I'm not sure why this is so because angular velocity should remain constant.
So, does this mean that an object released from rest into a hole has less angular velocity the deeper it falls? Is the decrease in angular velocity equal to the interior of earth's decrease with depth? Does this mean the object will fall down without tending to move towards the east wall of the hole as it falls?

"angular velocity should remain constant." Why? An object attached to the Earth has constant angular velocity, but once the object is flying through the air, there's nothing constraining it to have the same angular velocity.


I believe an object dropped into it would be thrown against the east wall of the hole as earth's linear velocity due to rotation decreases with depth. But I'm reading comments in other posts on here that say an object thrown upward has less angular velocity the higher it was thrown, which is why it will always land slightly west of the point it was thrown from.

Both are true. They are two different ways of saying the same thing.
All parts of the earth have the same angular velocity. However, different parts of the earth have different linear velocities (decreasing with depth/increasing with altitude).
On the other hand, a projectile has a constant linear velocity until a force acts on it. However, it has a changing angular velocity relative to the Earth's axis (decreasing with height/increasing with depth).
The Coriolis force is yet another formulation of the same idea. In a reference frame corotating with the earth, objects experience a Coriolis force proportional to $\mathbf{\Omega} \times \mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is a vector pointing from the center of the earth to the north pole. (There is also a centrifugal force, but it does not matter for this question.)
An object dropped into a deep hole will hit the east wall. You can view this as either (1) because of the decreasing linear velocity of the Earth with depth, (2) because of the increasing angular velocity of the projectile with depth, or (3) because of the Coriolis force, which is eastward for falling objects near the equator.


I believe an object dropped into it would be thrown against the east
wall of the hole as earth's linear velocity due to rotation decreases
with depth.

This is correct. The horizontal velocity of an object is independent of its vertical falling velocity, so the falling object ends up with excess horizontal velocity relative to parts of the Earth lower down the hole. Angular velocity is proportional to $v/r$, where $v$ is the tangential velocity. As an object falls, $v$ is constant, so the angular velocity increases as $r$ gets smaller.

But I'm reading comments in other posts here that say an object thrown
upward has less angular velocity the higher it was thrown, which is
why it will always land slightly west of the point it was thrown from.

This is also correct. If we have a tall vertical pole, the tangential velocity of the tower is greater at the top. An object thrown upwards towards the top of the tower retains the lower tangential horizontal velocity it had at ground level so, as it gets nearer the top of the tower, it tends to fall behind to the West ($\text{W}$) and eventually lands to the West. Again, since the horizontal tangential velocity $v$ remains constant and angular velocity is proportional to $v/r$, the angular velocity decreases as an object rises and  $r$ gets bigger.

This desn't make sense at all because just as the object falling into
the hole would drift east and contact the east wall of the hole, the
object falling from a tower above the ground should drift east and
land east of the tower. – Thomas Esposito

The important idea is that the object's horizontal tangential velocity does not change as it goes up or down. Let's say we are at the equator and the horizontal ground velocity is about $460 \ \text{m/s}$ East ($\text{E}$). Let's say for the sake of argument the top of the tower has a tangential velocity of $500 \ \text{m/s}$. Here is a table of the velocities and relative velocities on the way up and on the way back down:



Direction
Height
Ball velocity
Tower velocity
Relative velocity of ball




$\text{Up}$
$\text{Ground}$
$460$ $\text{E}$
460 $\text{E}$
$0$


$\text{Up}$
$\frac{1}{4} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$470$ $\text{E}$
$10$ $\text{W}$


$\text{Up}$
$\frac{1}{2} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$480$ $\text{E}$
$20$ $\text{W}$


$\text{Up}$
$\frac{3}{4} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$490$ $\text{E}$
$30$ $\text{W}$


----
$h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$500$ $\text{E}$
$40$ $\text{W}$


$\text{Down}$
$\frac{3}{4} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$490$ $\text{E}$
$30$ $\text{W}$


$\text{Down}$
$\frac{1}{2} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$480$ $\text{E}$
$20$ $\text{W}$


$\text{Down}$
$\frac{1}{4} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$470$ $\text{E}$
$10$ $\text{W}$


$\text{Down}$
$\text{Ground}$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$0$



All velocities are horizontal. It can be seen from the table, that at every instant on the way up and on the way back down, the object is always moving to the West relative to the base of the tower. Let's also say that the tower is on a cliff edge and the ball can continue downwards. Then the table would continue like this:



Direction
Height
Ball velocity
Tower velocity
Relative velocity of ball




$\text{Down}$
$\text{Ground}$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$0$


$\text{Down}$
$-\frac{1}{4} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$450$ $\text{E}$
$10$ $\text{E}$


$\text{Down}$
$-\frac{1}{2} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$440$ $\text{E}$
$20$ $\text{E}$


$\text{Down}$
$-\frac{3}{4} \ h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$430$ $\text{E}$
$30$ $\text{E}$


$\text{Down}$
$-h$
$460$ $\text{E}$
$420$ $\text{E}$
$40$ $\text{E}$



Underneath the ground the ball drifts to the East relative to the base of the tower.

This desn't make sense at all because just as the object falling into the hole would drift east and contact the east wall of the hole, the object falling from a tower above the ground should drift east and land east of the tower.

@ThomasEsposito The object does not start falling with same horizontal velocity as the top of the tower. It has the lower velocity it started with when it was launched from the ground ,so at every instant as it falls to the ground its is drifting to the West.

@ThomasEsposito I have extended my answer to address your comment.

@ThomasEsposito I am not absolutely sure if your last message was meant to be an admission of an error on your part and and an apology,, but I think I would prefer an upvote instead :_P

KDP, I do apologize and appreciate your answer.  After closing this site from my browser, it was difficult to find my post again and navigate this website.

@ThomasEsposito No problem. Do you understand the point I was making and do you think my answer is correct now?

This site is very difficult to navigate. As more comments are added, it becomes more difficult to see who made them, and to reply. Each original comment should have its own reply string, separated and distinguished from other reply strings by indentation. But, to KDP, I do agree with your answer. I can visualize how an object fired straight up on the equator at a geostationary satellite will miss to the West. It will then land to the West of the launch site.

@ThomasEsposito Thanks :-)
